# Can't figure out decision variable

Tags: algorithms, linear-programming, integer-programming

Good Evening, I am trying to solve an exercise related to my algorithm designing course. I have understood the question and what it asks. I am required to formulate an ILP and then relax it to according LP.

So I have n goods which I have to ship using three cargo companies. the Paths P i,j is composed of segments of road 'e' and some of these segments can be blocked as you can read from the exercise.

What I am getting confused here is how to determine the decision variables and its constraints? should I select e.g. x for a single path or x for a single good? and y for segment? I have to minimize the overall number of segments as low as possible for a single path.

Any guidance and clearance regarding this formulation would be a great help!
[image: The exercise]

Comment: What's the source of that image?  Note that we require you to credit the original source of all material written by others: https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing.  I've provided this feedback before.

Answer (score 1):

For each good $g_i$ you have three binary variables $d_{i,j}$: whether good $i$ it was delivered by truck 1, 2 or 3.

You make sure that exactly one truck takes the good: $b_{i,1} + b_{i,2} + b_{i,3} = 1$

Now you want to minimize the sum of all segments multiplied by the obstructions. So you minimize $\sum_{i, j} b_{i,j} \cdot x $ where $x$ is constant one for obstructed road or constant zero for a good one.